# What's the difference between these types of association in an UML Class Diagram?

Tags: uml, diagram, class-diagram

I never understood the difference between these types of association. How should I interpret and in which scenarios should I use each one?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one is a named association. The name of the association (being `purchase`) is pretty pointless unless you are doing some exotic stuff. In this case `User` and `Product` have both some array referencing objects on the other side.

The second and third are just alternative notations for the same thing. That is you have an association class `Purchase` which in this case connects `User` and `Product` by adding some (not shown) functionality/attributes. Here the classes left/right do not see each other. It's only `Purchase` which makes the references.

**Edit** As noted by [@JimL.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2596664/jim-l) the 2nd and 3rd differ in one respect: #2 has two`*` left and right where there should be a `1` to make it a match for #3. This would be the usual use for an association class. The `*` would make it different and probably very uncommon for the obvious application here.

Comment: I believe that in the second case, each Purchase can have any number of Users and any number of Products. Each of these is incorrect in a different way.

Comment: @JimL. You are right. I missed that bit. Will update my answer later. Thanks!

Comment: @JimL. I'm not sure whether the `*` would be wrong rather than just unusual (I can't think of a meaningful application this way, but there might be one?).

Comment: I can’t imagine a valid purchase without one purchasing user and one or more purchased things, unless the intention is to allow a purchase in progress that might be canceled. IMO, the intention should be clearly expressed. (E.g., phase specializations of in-progress, canceled, and completed, where completed has a min 1.)

Comment: @JimL. So would i think. Anyhow, it's not syntactically wrong. I.e. there is nothing said in UML that it needs to be `1`, right? (I 'm loath to crawl the specs for that one.)

Comment: Yes, the UML syntax seem valid here, although UML was not designed to prevent nonsense. You would need something resembling OntoUML for that.

Comment: @JimL. Your reading of case 2 is not correct: An instance of the asssociation class `Puchase` is still a link connecting exactly one user with exactly one product (as stated in @AxelScheithauer's answer below. Consequently, the case 2 model is perfectly correct.

Comment: I disbelieve. There is no such thing as a link anymore in UML. There is only an instance specification. Moreover, when the association class owns the association ends, which are each 0..*, every instance spec will have zero or more values for those ends, not exactly one. Please provide evidence otherwise.

Comment: @JimL. An instance specification (m1) specifies instances (m0). In case of associations the instances are also called links. Therefore, I agree that there are no links in UML, instead there are statements about links.

Comment: @JimL. For the semantics, it makes no difference, whether association ends are owned or not. In an instance specification of an association, all slots for the member ends (owned or not) must have exactly one value. Unfortunately I could not find this constraint in the specification. But if this is not true, the links would not connect the same number of elements, as the association. E.g. an instance of a _binary_ association must link exactly _two_ objects. The multiplicity of the defining feature limits the number of binary links, _not_ the number of values in the slots of binary links.

Comment: Despite all of this: it depends on what you want to model. If a model is ambiguous it's pretty useless. You need some context and a goal. That is what you try to model. Not to decrypt a broken model.

Answer (score 2):

Given your diagrams all three cases are **equivalent**. So, I would go with the simplest version.

Adding a Purchase class allows to define features and behaviors of the link objects.

In the second case, Purchase is classifying the *binary* links between User objects and Product objects. That means each Purchase object is the link between *exactly one* User object and *exactly one* Product object. The outcome is the same as in the third case. Only there you have two link objects and one regular object, making the model a little more complicated. On the other hand, in this case you don't need to explain to your readers what an AssociationClass is.

In earlier versions of UML the two latter cases had a subtle difference. If the two ends of the AssociationClass are unique, each pair of User and Product can have at most one link. For a Purchase this is probably not what you want, because the user might buy the same product multiple times. But a stack overflow user can earn each badge only once. The AssociationClass would allow to model this.

Unfortunately this distinction has been thrown out. Therefore, AssociationClasses now don't have more expressive power than regular Classes, making them obsolete. I wrote a [specification issue](https://issues.omg.org/issues/UMLR-757) asking to put uniqueness back in.

Comment: Notice that, since the default value for `isUnique` is true, case 2 and case 3 are not really equivalent. Also, the new AssociationClass concept is a useful concise representation of cases like your `StackOverflowUser`-`Badge case. So, why do you think, with the extended semantics it's no longer needed?

Comment: Well, there is this note on page 201 in the specification: 

_NOTE. Even when all ends of the AssociationClass have isUnique=true, it is possible to have several instances associating the same set of instances of the end Classes._ 

This means we can have multiple objects linking the same two instances of User and Product. 

For background info: https://issues.omg.org/issues/UML22-21. The cited paper is http://doi.ieeecomputersociety.org/10.1109/TSE.2007.37

Comment: The paper is available here: http://afrodita.rcub.bg.ac.rs/~dmilicev/pubs/mdd/trumlassoc.zip

Comment: Thanks for the explanations and the pointers (in fact, I looked at the paper of Dragan Milicev in the past, but forgot about it). As a consequence, when unique links are the intended reading, a separate constraint needs to be attached to the AssociationClass, right? But then, still, the AssociationClass pattern of case 2 (with one class rectangle and one association line)  is a bit less complex compared to the pattern of case 3 (with one class rectangle and two association lines). Doesn't this (small) adavantage justify to keep the AssociationClass notation?

Comment: @GerdWagner. Yes, an additional constraint is needed. Case 2 definitely has the advantage of a more compact notation. But on the other hand, readers need to be familiar with association classes, which is not always the case.

Answer (score 1):

So, according to my college teacher, the first and second one are equivalent. The second one would be "more correct" if the purchase had other atributes, since it doesn't you would opt for the first.

The third one differs a bit from the rest in the way that there can be multiple purchases where the User X bought the Product Y.

So, the first and second would be useful if we only want one record of a purchase between a User and a Product, and the third if we wanted to keep a purchase history for example

Comment: Your college teacher is not 100% correct. UML specs state at §11.5.3.1:  **When one or more ends of the Association have isUnique=false, it is possible to have several links associating the same
set of instances.** although the default value for isUnique is true.